# Como criar somatório com "sum" com multiplas colunas queryover

Tags: c#, sql, query, nhibernate

Galera preciso criar uma consulta com queryOver(Nhibernate) C#, para somar mais de uma coluna. Exemplo em sql puro:

```
SELECT SUM(coluna1 + coluna2 + coluna3 + coluna4)
FROM tabela
```

Primeiramente eu fiz dessa forma:

```
Tabela tabela = null;
Session.QueryOver<Tabela>(() => tabela)
           .Select(Projections.Sum<Tabela>(t => t.coluna1))
           .Select(Projections.Sum<Tabela>(t => t.coluna2))
           .Select(Projections.Sum<Tabela>(t => t.coluna3))
           .Select(Projections.Sum<Tabela>(t => t.coluna4))
```

Mas dessa forma somo cada coluna e gera 4 colunas, gostaria de somar todas e gerar uma coluna só.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solução baseado [nesta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26590517/2290538).

Você pode utilizar `Projections.SqlFunction`, para aplicar um *projection* customizado no `Projections.Sum`, utilizando o `NHibernate.Dialect.Function.VarArgsSQLFunction` para informar o template do bind SQL.

Algo similar ao seguinte exemplo:

```cs
Tabela itemAlias = null;

var query = Session.QueryOver<Tabela>(() => itemAlias)
    .Select(Projections.Sum(
        Projections.SqlFunction(
            new NHibernate.Dialect.Function.VarArgsSQLFunction("(", " + ", ")"),
            NHibernateUtil.Double,
            Projections.Property(() => itemAlias.coluna1),
            Projections.Property(() => itemAlias.coluna2),
            Projections.Property(() => itemAlias.coluna3),
            Projections.Property(() => itemAlias.coluna4)
        )
    )
);

var result = query.SingleOrDefault<double>();
```

O SQL gerado por essa *query* será algo simular a isso (dependendo do banco de dados):

```sql
select sum((THIS_.COLUNA1 + THIS_.COLUNA2 + THIS_.COLUNA3 + THIS_.COLUNA4)) as Y0_
from TABELA THIS_
```

Comment: isso mesmo que precisava, funcionou certinho, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo pensar numa forma "NHibernate" de fazer isso. A solução seria executar uma query pura

```
var query = "select C.prop1 + C.prop2 from Classe as C";

var sum = session.CreateQuery(query).UniqueResult<double>();
```

**Edit:**

Talvez você possa tentar desta forma

```
Session.QueryOver<Table>(() => tabela)
   .Select(Projections.Sum<Table>(t => t.Prop1 + t.Prop2 + t.Prop3 + t.Prop4));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas dessa forma já sabia, precisava msm com queryOver. @jbueno.

Comment: Você usa NHibernate com Linq?

Comment: Uso tambem. Editei a pergunta e coloquei como estava fazendo anteriormente com queryOver, só que daquela forma gera 4 colunas.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na edição @MarcosVinicius

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, parece que não da pra colocar mais de uma coluna. Apresenta exceção:
Message=a variável 't' de tipo Tabela' é referenciada no escopo '', mas ela não está definida.